# is mongo.update() gets an immediate write lock?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to understand if issuing a mongo.update call will take a write lock immediately, or will it first take a read lock to get the data and only then will take a write lock to modify the data.

Also i am trying to understand what will be the behaviour when using other mongo functions like findOneAndUpdate or findAndModify

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/), when modifying a single document, both `findAndModify` and the `update` method atomically update the document. This implies that a write lock is taken out immediately. If you want to atomically update multiple records you have to use the `$isolated` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).